# Theory : starting Pex Exploration and number of PUT generated

Tags: performance, pex

I read many papers about pex , I'm focus on the explorations strategies . I understand that the Fitnex strategy is default used but I don't understand how Pex create the first parametrized unit test .

Where I can find this information ?

By sperimental tests I think :
- If parameter is "int" start with 0
- If parameter is "bool" start with false
- If parameter is an object start with Null

Is it correct ?

Now about Fitnex strategy and solver constraints Z3 I think that it is able to solve only one constrain by iteration , sorry for my little English now I do an example :

Suppose to have the following method :

```
public void branchOverTests(bool a, bool b)
{
1   if (a)
    {
2       Console.WriteLine("B1");
    }
    else
    {
3       Console.WriteLine("B2");
    }
4   if (b)
    {
5       Console.WriteLine("B3");
    }
    else
    {
6       Console.WriteLine("B4");
    }
}
```

Numbers are lines identify, Pex generate 3 tests :

```
--- Test 1
branchOverTests(a=false,b=false)
Path: 1F 3T 4F 6T
return target != (ClassMethod)null;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a == false;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a == false;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a == false && b == false;

--- Test 2
branchOverTests(a=false,b=true)
Path: 1F 3T 4T 5T
return target != (ClassMethod)null;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a == false;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a == false;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && b != false && a == false;

Note: From Test 1 Flipped last branch: 
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a == false && b == false; 
-> return target != (ClassMethod)null && b != false && a == false; 
=> b = true

--- Test 3
branchOverTests(a=true,b=false)
Path: 1T 2T 4F 6T
return target != (ClassMethod)null;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false && b == false;

Note: From Test 2 Resolve second condition of last branch:
return return target != (ClassMethod)null && b != false && a == false; 
-> return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false && b == false; 
=> a = true
=> return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false;
=> return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false;
```

But the most efficient set of parametrized tests is :

```
branchOverTests(a=false,b=false)
branchOverTests(a=true,b=true)
```

After Test 1 :

```
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a == false;
-> return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false;
=> a = true
=> return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false && b != false;
=> b = true
```

Ideal Test 2 :

```
branchOverTests(a=true,b=true)
Path: 1T 2T 4T 5T
return target != (ClassMethod)null;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false;
return target != (ClassMethod)null && a != false && b != false;
```

Is That I think correct ?

Thanks best regards.

Answer (score 2):

Pex always starts with default values, just like you described. That is the first test case. Then Pex explores all possible combinations of execution paths. (The Fitnex strategy guides Pex, but that isn't important for your question.) By default, whenever Pex discovers a new test case that increases branch coverage, it emits another test case.  Pex is eager in this way, and the resulting test suite is not guaranteed to be minimal, as you discovered. But usually it is pretty close. (Internally, Pex also considered the (true,true) at the end, but didn't create yet another test case as it wouldn't have increased branch coverage.)